# Why does <> 'null' works in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, comparison

Hope the question is not too generic. Couldn't find anything on the site or in SQL documentation:

While coding, i tested this, and to my surprise it worked:

```
SELECT * FROM cal_entry WHERE cal_entry.parent_id <> 'null'
```

It actually shows the rows without the ones with `NULL` values (these are real `NULL` values in database, not strings with `'null'` inside).

According to the docs, I should have used `NOT NULL`, of course. By the way, it doesn't work with `= 'null'`, like it is correctly stated in the docs.

Can someone explain that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `parent_id` in an `int` column the query will return all non-null, non-zero rows:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT NULL AS parent_id UNION ALL
    SELECT 0 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2
) AS cal_entry
WHERE cal_entry.parent_id <> 'null'
-- returns 1 and 2 but not 0!
```

When comparing a number to string MySQL will convert the string to number. Some examples:

- `'null'` becomes 0
- `'asdf'` becomes 0
- `'1asdf'` becomes `123`
- `'1'` becomes 1

Your query will behave like:

```
WHERE cal_entry.parent_id <> 0
```

Comment: Yes, this should be the accepted answer, as i tested with a `parent_id` at `0` and it was actually filtered out of the results. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are selecting all rows where `<> 'null'` is true.

Comparing(equals or not-equals) to null is null, so if a row where `cal_entry.parent_id` is null, your condition will be false/null.

So your query gets all rows that are not null, nor contain the string 'null'.

(Note, you could just as well have written `<>'something_else'`)

Comment: yes you're right, that's logic, I should have thought about it a little more, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

this operator give you result of not equal to. ex. $var != null.
we write in mysql as <>. this is kind of validation that the value shoud never be equal to null.

Answer (score 0):

When working with null following two statements should always be taken note of  -

1. An expression can be null, but it can never be equal to null.
2. Two nulls are never equal to each other.

So, in your query wherever there is a comparison `null<>null` it returns true by second statement.

Also, always account the possibility that some rows might contain null -

```
Select * from cal_entry where cal_entry.parent_id!=10
```

This query would leave out the rows with null entries. Instead use -

```
Select * from cal_entry where cal_entry.parent_id!=10 or cal_entry.parent_id is null
```